# Yii2: How to find version

Tags: yii2, version

I need to show the version of Yii2 in the command line.
I don't want to write extra code using `Yii::getVersion()`.

I expect something like:

```
$ ./yii --version
2.0.49
```

Is there a command line onliner to get the Yii2 version?

Answer (score 1):

There is no command that would output only version of yii. But if you run `yii help` or only `yii` with no argument the first line will contain the version.
For example:

> This is Yii version 2.0.48.1.

Another option is to use composer to get installed version of `yiisoft/yii2` package:

```
> composer show yiisoft/yii2
name     : yiisoft/yii2
descrip. : Yii PHP Framework Version 2
keywords : framework, yii2
versions : * 2.0.48.1
...
```

Or you can include a php code snippet to display version:

```
> php -r "require './vendor/autoload.php'; echo \yii\BaseYii::getVersion();"
2.0.48.1
```

I know you didn't want to write php code with `Yii::getVersion()`, I've only added this option for the sake of completeness.